# Como faço pra verificar se existe um número em uma string?

Tags: python

```py
notas = input('Digite uma nota de 0 à 10: ')
if notas.isnumeric() or 0 < notas < 10:
    print('Nota inválida!')
```

Pessoal, eu quero fazer a verificação se o que o usuário digitou contém algum número,
Estou tentando dessa forma, porém não estou conseguindo.
Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `input` retorna uma *string*.

Portanto, o primeiro teste funciona, porque [o método `isnumeric` *pertence à classe `str`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric).

No entanto, o Python não realiza a conversão de tipos para fazer comparações, conforme certas linguagens fazem. Assim, como um objeto `str` (*string*) não permite a comparação de maior e menor com inteiros (objetos do tipo `int`), o segundo teste gera um erro.

---

A solução, de toda forma, é converter a *string* para inteiro. Só que você pode fazer isso de duas maneiras:

1. Somente durante o teste;

   ```py
   if nota.isnumeric() and 0 < int(nota) < 10:
   ```
2. Logo na atribuição;

   ```py
   nota = int(input('...'))

   if 0 < nota < 10:
   ```

Se você optar pela segunda opção, a própria classe `int` cuidará de converter o texto do usuário para um número inteiro. No entanto, se o usuário digitar algo errado, a classe irá lançar uma exceção de  `ValueError`, o que pode fazer o programa parar, se caso você queira que ele execute infinitamente. A partir daí, você iria ter que implementar outras estruturas da linguagem, para poder "amenizar" esse erro e mostrar uma mensagem personalizada, podendo "continuar" a execução.

Já se você optar pela primeira opção, você estará primeiro garantindo que o texto é um valor numérico válido, para só então convertê-lo e testar se ele está entre 0 e 10. Dessa forma, você estará *evitando uma exceção* que já pode ser tratada com um simples teste, que é esse que você faz, e poderá tratar um valor inválido só colocando um bloco `else`.

Enfim, fica à sua escolha.

Comment: Teria algum local onde eu poderia verificar a documentação ou embasar essa sua linha de raciocínio meu caro ?